# なります intransitive verb - volitional/non-volitional

Tags: grammar, verbs

なります is an intransitive verb, but it could either be volitional or non-volitional, right? Please see the below examples; are they correct?

> 日本語が上手に**なるように**、毎日勉強しています。(なります is non-volitional)
>
> 弁護士に**なるために**、法律を勉強しています。(なります is volitional)

Comment: I think they might be trying to get at the idea that certain subjects cannot use the volitional form of a verb, because the subject itself cannot have volition. I'm not sure if that's what they're getting at, but it's my best guess. Even though, yes, they didn't bring any volitional forms into the examples to put it to the test.

Comment: I think that OP is making a distinction between [types of verbs](https://grammar2understand.wordpress.com/2013/04/11/japanese-volitional-and-non-volitional-verbs-an-introduction-to-the-concepts/), regardless of what form they are conjugated into. For example, some volitional verbs (意志動詞) are 食べる, 持つ, and some non-volitional verbs (無意志動詞) are 分かる, 知る.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By "volitional", I think I understand you to mean what are also called "will verbs" or "controllable verbs" in English, 意志動詞 in Japanese; and by "non-volitional", "non-will verbs" or "uncontrollable verbs", 無意志動詞 in Japanese?

*The term "volitional" here is possibly a bit confusing just given it is the name of a verb form, too, so I will just use "controllable" and "uncontrollable" instead.*

If that is what you were referring to, you are right in thinking that なる is both a "controllable" verb 意志動詞 and "uncontrollable" verb 無意志動詞, depending on the circumstance. For instance:

> **意志動詞:** 親戚が医者になった。
>
> A relative became a doctor. (controllable, e.g. through going to medical school)
>
> **無意志動詞:** 時刻が正午になった。
>
> It (the time) became noon. (uncontrollable)

---

Looking at your examples, first you have:

> 日本語が上手になるように、毎日勉強しています。

This is grammatically OK, but I personally would favour saying (the very similar; just sounds more natural to me):

> 日本語が上手く{うまく}なるように、毎日勉強しています。

In any case, you can't strictly "control" being good at a language, so this is indeed an example of an "uncontrollable" form of なる.

Looking at your second example:

> 弁護士になるために、法律を勉強しています。

This is a good example of a "controllable" form of なる, as - just as with the doctor example I gave - this person essentially chose to be a lawyer (by going to law school/choosing to studying law).

---

The other thing to bear in mind is that for instances where なる is a "controllable" verb in that you can use *either* **なれる**ように *or* **なる**ために:

> ◎ 偉{えら}い人に**なれるように**勉強しています。
>
> ◎ 偉い人に**なるために**勉強しています。
>
> ?? 偉い人に**なるように**勉強しています。(sounds odd/unnatural, but I think understandable)

On the other hand, for those "uncontrollable" instances of なる, you should *only* use **なる**ように :

> × 野菜が大きく**なれるように**水をたくさんやります。(incorrect)
>
> × 野菜が大きく**なるために**水をたくさんやります。(incorrect)
>
> ◎ 野菜が大きく**なるように**水をたくさんやります。

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Chocolate この場合には、「volitional vs non-volitional」ってちょっと不明ですね。多分、「control vs non-control」＝「支配ある・なし」の方がいいと思います。意志動詞とは「する」や「食べる」のように動作・行為を表す動詞のことです、無意志同士とは、「ある」などの動作・行為を表さない動詞のことです。無意志動詞は、命令・禁止・願望・意志・依頼・可能・使役・受身を表す形にすることができません。しかし、言うまでもなく、意志動詞と無意志動詞の両方で使われる動詞の場合には、時々その形にすることができます、時々できません。例えば、忘れる：意思動詞として「そんなこと、早く忘れよう。」、無意志動詞として「その人の名前、、忘れちゃった〜。」の例があります。前者の場合には、自分の意志・支配で、忘れることができます。後者の場合には、自分の意志・支配がなくて、忘れてしまいました。この「volitional vs non-volitional」はこのような違いですね。では、「なれるvsなる」は、役立つ例だと思います。意志動詞の場合には、「ために」の前には意志動詞が、「ように」の前には意志動詞の可能形が用いられる。しかし、「なる」は両方の動詞ですから、意志動詞なら「なるために」も「なれるように」もOKです、無意志動詞なら「なるように」だけOKですね。

Comment: おおっ！　volitional/non-volitionalって、「意志形かどうか」の話じゃなくて、「意志動詞vs無意志動詞」のことだったんですね・・・

Comment: @Chocolate 全くその通りですね！:)