# Why is volitional verb used before 〜ように (in order to)?

Tags: volitional-form

> 「今日の登校中、<ラタトスク>の機関員が十香の嫉妬を**煽るように**いろいろと工作をするわ。士道はそれを受けつつ、上手く対応してちょうだい」

Hi. The context is that 琴里, the speaker and command of the 機関員, is talking to 士道. 琴里 will ask the 機関員 to fan 十香’s jealousy and hope 士道 would cope with that.

My question is, we are taught that when 〜ように indicate purpose, volitional verbs can’t be used before 〜ように. But in this case, 煽る is a volitional verb so it breaks the rule. Is this a technical mistake on the writer’s part or is what I have been taught inaccurate?
Thank you.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood what a volitional verb is and are confusing volitional with transitive. It means the volitional conjugation, i.e. the  おう form such as しよう 食べよう 飲もう 行こう. 煽る is the default conjugation of the verb, and its volitional form is 煽ろう.

Comment: ^ James, 意志形（～う、～よう）じゃなくて、「意志動詞」「無意志動詞」のことじゃないでしょうか・・・　私もここでわからんかったやつ⇒https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68991/9831

Comment: Related, perhaps? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/69030/9831